# Setenv $PATH not functioning properly

Tags: perl, setenv

I wrote a shell script which sets the `$PATH` variable to a directory which contains a shell and a Perl script.

I am able to run the shell script with the current working directory set to any random directory, but the Perl script is different.

Is there any difference between running the two?

The error thrown is

```
Can't open perl script "script.pl" : No such file or directory
```

Though the file exists in the very same folder as the shell script.

Comment: Yes. One is a shell script, the other is a Perl script. They are two completely different things. You should include the code you tried, including all the relevant information. Preferably create an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: That error doesn't come from the shell. It comes from `perl`. That means the script was found, and the script was passed to `perl`, but some problem occurred. Are you using setuid or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> *if I run script.pl, it says command not found.*

Just like with shell scripts, you will need to make the Perl script executable (`chmod u+x script.pl`), and it will need to have a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/perl`).

```
$ export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin

$ cat >$HOME/bin/script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello, world!\n";
^D

$ chmod u+x $HOME/bin/script.pl

$ script.pl
Hello, world!
```

Comment: I have edited the question adding the error message.I have given execute permissions to the Perl script as well and used the shebang too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of things that you may need to check:

1. the execute permissions (ie: `chmod +x script.pl`)
2. that the perl script has `#!/usr/bin/perl` as its first line.
3. When you are trying to launch the perl script, are you typing in the whole name of the file including any extensions? (ie: `script.pl` and not `script`) I usually don't use extensions for scripts that I keep in a directory in `$PATH` to make things easier.

It would really help if you showed us what you were typing or the error.

Edit: Another thing you could check would be the ownership of the script. I just made a script as root and it threw up some errors like what you're experiencing.

```
[root@computer perms-test]# chmod 744 perms.pl  # As Root, give permissions
[root@computer perms-test]# ll
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 96 Apr 22 17:41 perms.pl
[root@computer perms-test]# exit
exit
[user@computer:perms-test]ll
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 96 Apr 22 17:41 perms.pl
[user@computer:perms-test]./perms.pl        # User can't run script
bash: ./perms.pl: Permission denied
[user@computer:perms-test]echo 'PATH=/home/user/perms-test:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
[user@computer:perms-test]. ~/.bashrc       # Reinitialise .bashrc
[user@computer:perms-test]mkdir random-dir
[user@computer:perms-test]cd random-dir/
[user@computer:random-dir]perms.pl
bash: /home/user/perms-test/perms.pl: Permission denied
[user@computer:random-dir]perl perms.pl # In a different dir, can't find script
Can't open perl script "perms.pl": No such file or directory
[user@computer:random-dir]cd ..
[user@computer:perms-test]perl perms.pl 
the script allowed you to run it.
```

Comment: I have edited the question adding the error message.I have given execute permissions to the Perl script as well and used the shebang too.I am running the script like : "perl script.pl" .Even if I run "perl script" it throws the same error.Just running "script" shows Permissions denied and running "script.pl" shows Command not found.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script as "perl script.pl", the system will use the path environment to locate the perl interpreter but not your script.  The script name is being passed to the interpreter as its arg.  If the script is not in the cwd, you'll need to include its path.

> Just running "script" shows Permissions denied and running "script.pl" shows Command not found.

That tells me 2 things.  1) The script's name doesn't include the .pl ext and 2) when called without the ext, it does find the script within the path but its permissions aren't set correctly for you to execute it.

As has been stated by others, you need to assign the correct permissions to allow you to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

> *The error thrown is*
>   *`Can't open perl script "script.pl" : No such file or directory`*

This is an analog of what you've done:

```
$ export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin

$ cat >$HOME/bin/script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello, world!\n";
^D

$ chmod u+x $HOME/bin/script.pl

$ perl script.pl
Can't open perl script "script.pl": No such file or directory
```

That's wrong. The path is searched, but it's searched for `perl`. This is what you should be using:

```
$ script.pl
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Then I didn't guess what you did correctly. What did you do differently than my guess? Why are you making us guess?